# I need a template system (XML-based) that can be used both with PHP (server-side) and Javascript (client side)

Tags: php, javascript, templates

I am looking for a good template system (preferably XML-based) that provides implementations both for PHP and Javascript.

This would enable me to write templates for some elements that are either:
 - Populated on server side : when simply displaying those, in "reader" mode.
 - Or instantiated / populated on client side : when creating new instances of these objects, in the admin backend, using Javascript.

Does such a system exist? Or maybe an there is alternative to handle those needs ?

Comment: Let me ask this:  Why?  What are you trying to accomplish that requires parsing of templates in *both* PHP and JS?  Why not simply let PHP return a generated template via AJAX?

Comment: That's a good question. And maybe also a good alternative solution to my problem.
I'll see depending of what others propose to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not XML-based, but the only one I know available in JS and PHP is [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), which is a fairly simple template engine, but it's getting very popular in the JS community.

And if you are using PHP5.3, Matthew Weier O'Phinney has just released [an implementation of mustache for php5.3](http://github.com/weierophinney/phly_mustache)

Here is a pretty good introduction to it: http://blog.couch.io/post/622014913/mustache-js

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Xslt?  Not all browsers support it, but a good majority do.

Comment: To me, XSLT has several drawbacks :
* It only transforms XML data, not native hierarchy of objects.
* It is ugly and super-verbose
* I would have to struggle with the different bugs / implementation of all browsers. 
I definitiely need some separate library that has been tested and enforced against most browsers.

Comment: Ugly and super verbose?!  Don't believe the fanyboi hype, XSLT is a succinct and powerful tool in it's own right.  This may not be the best way to use it, but at least it satisfies most of the criteria in your question - I reckon it's the only templating language that is *natively* supported on most browsers.